# Exposing a website externally

Tags: iis, web-server, asp.net

I got asked to set up a website that could be accessed externally in IIS.

We have a web server that has a website currently available externally on it. It sits under an "External Website" Site in IIS. So I created a different application under External Website pointing that to a different folder and hooked it up to use a different application pool (new).

It works on the internal URL but when I try it externally (on my iphone) the one that works externally is viewable, but the new one I created is not.

Unfortunately with my development background/knowledge I don't know if this is something that I can fix (ie. a setting in IIS either on the site or AppPool), or if its related to a dns/firewall setting or something to allow access from the outside world.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated. The new site is similar to the old site (as in ASP.NET MVC) but its got different content, etc.. The error I'm getting is a 404 error.

Comment: Jen, Please provide more details on this. Is that working on same IP range? DNS pointed correctly? When you have updated DNS? LISTENING ports ? etc.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion - it was inside the External website, and I didn't make any DNS changes.  It appeared to be a time delay thing.  Someone tested it hours after I tested it and it worked.  From then on it was working.

So yeah when I tested it internally it was working fine but external access seemed to take a bit longer?  No one modified anything, so I'm guessing it was some kind of DNS delay or something?!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your new application is not working externally, is probably because it is not inside the "External Website" site.

I'm assuming that your network admin setup port forwarding, so that requests to your external ip address are forwarded to a custom port that was setup for the external web site. This means that only the external web site is accessible to the outside network.

You didn't mention which version of Windows you are using, so I'm assuming it's Windows 2008 (R2).

You will have to make sure that your new application is inside the "External Website" site. Take a look at the bindings of the external web site. If you right-click that site and select "Edit Bindings", then you should see which port it is listening on.

You should be able to view that content from the INTERNAL network by specifying the port (e.g. http://webserver:8080/). If you configured your new application correctly, then you should be able to view it from the inside via that same port as well.

If you send more information on your IIS structure then I can be more specific.